# Currying of chain of functions linked by -:

Tags: haskell, currying

I am learning Haskell with [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) tutorial. I am at [Walk the line](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#walk-the-line) section. It introduced very helpful operator:

```
x -: f = f x
```

It allows taking initial state and chain functions with this operator:

```
(0,0) -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 -: landLeft (-1) -: landRight (-2)
```

My question is how could I take this chain of functions and give it a separate name? For example:

```
chain = landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 -: landLeft (-1) -: landRight (-2)
(0,0) -: chain
```

Comment: `chain x = x landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give an explicit argument

```
chain x = x -: landLeft 1 -: landRight 4 -: landLeft (-1) -: landRight (-2)
```

This operator is not very conducive to chaining operations by themselves, it's really just `flip ($)`, and as we know you can't do something like `chain = h $ g $ f` to replace `h $ g $ f $ x`.  Instead, it's common to replace to the `$` with `.`, as in `chain = h . g . f`.  If you want to use the left-to-right style instead, I'd recommend making a separate operator to be the equivalent of `flip (.)`:

```
(-:) = flip ($)
(-.) = flip (.)

chain = landLeft 1 -. landRight 4 -. landLeft (-1) -. landRight (-2)
```

Or you could use operators from `Control.Arrow` along with your `-:` operator:

```
import Control.Arrow

chain = landLeft 1 >>> landRight 4 >>> landLeft (-1) >>> landRight (-2)

> x -: chain
```

Actually, given the operators in `Control.Arrow`, you can define `landLeft` and `landRight`:

```
landLeft c = first (+c)
landRight c = second (+c)
landBoth c = (+c) *** (+c)
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not. The reason why is that

```
chain = x -: y -: z
```

means

```
chain = z (y x)
```

So, when you apply `w -: chain`, you would get

```
w -: chain = z (y x) w
```

which is essentially garbage, and likely the type checker will complain.
You instead want to have

```
w -: chain = z (y (x w)))
```

What you could do is defining the chain using the composition operator `(.)`.

```
chain = z . y . x
```

Note that the order is *opposite* to the one you had in `-:`. For reversing the order, you could instead use

```
import Control.Arrow (>>>)
chain = x >>> y >>> z
```